Is there a way to merge bowtie polygons into valid polygon by inserting merge point
I have created a shapefile using QGIS, but some of the polygons in the shapefile intersect at a singular point creating a bowtie polygon. I wish to add a point adjacent to both of the polygons that can be used to merge the two polygons into one that has no intersections with itself. Below is an image of an example of two polygons creating a bowtie. I wish to insert the point at one of the blue spots to merge the two. The new point must not cause intersections between the newly merges polygon and other polygons either.
Bowtie polygons
I'm having trouble determining where the blue point should be. I believe the polygons are represented clockwise in the shapefile, which means in the example scenario the new point would be in either
(LowerPolygonNextX,UpperPolygonPreviousY) or (UpperPolygonNextX,LowerPolygonPreviousY), but I need a general approach to this based on their relation to each other. I think I also need to handle the case where one (or both) of the polygons start and end in this point, as this duplicate point may cause some issues with self intersecting.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I ended up solving this by connecting the two polygons using their existing points rather than creating a new point like this:
Bowtie polygon connected.
Here is the code used for anyone interested. Polys is a list of sublists of points.
def merge_bowtie_polygons(polys):
print('merging')
counter = 0
seen_points = set()
removed_indexes = set()
merged = False
for poly in polys:
    sublist_set = set(map(tuple, poly))
    seen_points.update(sublist_set)
polys.sort(key=len,reverse=False)
for i in range(len(polys)):
    sublist1 = polys[i]
    for j in range(i + 1, len(polys)):
        sublist2 = polys[j]
        for point in sublist1:
            if point in sublist2:
                polys[j] = merge(sublist1, sublist2, point)
                removed_indexes.add(i)
                merged = True
                counter += 1
                break
        if merged:
            merged = False
            break
newPolys = []
for i in range(len(polys)):
    if i not in removed_indexes:
        newPolys.append(polys[i])
print(counter)
return newPolys


def merge(sublist1,sublist2,point):
sublist1index = sublist1.index(point)
sublist2index = sublist2.index(point)
sublist1beginning = sublist1[:sublist1index]
sublist1end = sublist1[sublist1index:]
sublist2beginning = sublist2[:sublist2index]
sublist2end = sublist2[sublist2index:]
newPolygon = sublist1beginning + sublist2end + sublist2beginning + sublist1end
seen_points = set()
cleanedPolygon = []
for point in newPolygon:
    if point in seen_points:
        continue
    cleanedPolygon.append(point)
    seen_points.add(point)
cleanedPolygon.append(newPolygon[-1])
return cleanedPolygon

